# How to use proxies with cloudscraper

Tags: web-scraping, proxy, captcha

I would like to use proxies with cloudscraper.

When I don't pass any proxies all works fine:

```
import cloudscraper

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()

response = scraper.post(url, headers=headers, json=params)
```

But when I use proxies:

```
import cloudscraper

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()

proxies = {'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:9990', 'https': 'http://127.0.0.1:9990'}

response = scraper.post(url, headers=headers, json=params, proxies=proxies)
```

I get this error:

```
Detected a Cloudflare version 2 Captcha challenge, This feature is not available in the 
opensource (free) version.
```

How can I solve this? Why don't I get this error when I don't pass proxies?

Comment: Did you find out any more information by now @Laura?